# Can not delete a file in home directory

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I was removing Dropbox from my computer, and it deleted the entire Desktop folder!

I was able to recover the files, but now there is a file named `Desktop` in my home directory which cannot be deleted. It appears to be a link to `/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Desktop`, which no longer exists.

My macOS version is Monterey 12.5.1.

Comment: Can you post ([edit] the original question) the output of the command `ls -la ~/`

Comment: @Allan I suggest `ls -lae ~/` so as to include any ACLs which may be blocking delete.

Comment: That’s a good idea @Gilby - I was just starting off with trying to see what we’re working with a sym link or something else.